# env: node: is returning a no such file or directory exist

Tags: javascript, bash, macos, cron

So im sure this is a macOS related issue.

I have the following sh in my mac.

```
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck disable=SC2164
cd  /Users/chrismoreno/Desktop/MintCode/mint-scrappy-doo/__tests__/desktopTests
/usr/local/bin/node npm run test signedIn.js
```

This the cron I wrote:

```
*/5 * * * * /Users/user/Desktop/directory/repo/.provision/bash.sh > /tmp/stdout.log 2> /tmp/stderr.log
```

But I keep getting an error of

```
env: node: no such file or directory
```

I am running out of ideas.  the sh is executable and I have already done a which node and npm and they are both in that path.  if i run the same command from the command line it works.  however, it does not work on the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: That error message comes from the `env` command, which you are not using any of the code you have shown. That's the error you would get if you called node via `/usr/bin/env node <path_to_file>` (or had that in a shebang). That's not present in code you have posted.

Comment: @jordanm yours saying to do this `/usr/bin/env node` after the `cd` ?

Comment: I'm saying the code that produced that error message isn't included in your question